# Repository pattern - make it testable, DI and IoC friendly and IDisposable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern, idisposable

What I have:

```
public interface IRepository
{
   IDisposable CreateConnection();
   User GetUser();
   //other methods, doesnt matter
}

public class Repository
{
   private SqlConnection _connection;

   IDisposable CreateConnection()
   {
      _connection = new SqlConnection();
      _connection.Open();
      return _connection;
   }

   User GetUser()
   {
      //using _connection gets User from Database
      //assumes _connection is not null and open
   }
   //other methods, doesnt matter 
}
```

This enables classes that are using IRepository to be easily testable and IoC containers friendly. However someone using this class has to call CreateConnection before calling any methods that are getting something from database, otherwise exception will be thrown. This itself is kind of good - we dont want to have long lasting connections in application. So using this class I do it like this.

```
using(_repository.CreateConnection())
{
    var user = _repository.GetUser();
    //do something with user
}
```

Unfortunetelly this is not very good solution because people using this class (including even me!) often forget to call `_repository.CreateConnection()` before calling methods to get something from database.

To resolve this I was looking at Mark Seemann blog post [SUT Double](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/06/15/sut-double/) where he implements Repository pattern in correct way. Unfortunately he makes Repository implement IDisposable, which means I cannot simply inject it by IoC and DI to classes and use it after, because after just one usage it will be disposed. He uses it once per request and he uses ASP.NET WebApi capabilities to dispose it after request processing is done. This is something I cannot do because I have my classes instances which use Repository working all the time.

What is the best possible solution here? Should I use some kind of factory that will give me IDisposable IRepository ? Will it be easily testable then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few problematic spots in your design. First of all, your `IRepository` interface implements multiple levels of abstractions. Creating a user is a much higher level concept than connection management. By placing these behaviours together you are breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) which dictates that a class should only have one responsibility, one reason to change. You are also violating the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) that pushes us toward narrow role interfaces.

On top of that, the `CreateConnection()` and GetUser method are temporal coupled. [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) is a code smell and you are already witnessing this to be a problem, because you are able to forget the call to `CreateConnection`.

Besides this, the creation of the connection is something you will start to see on every repository in the system and every piece of business logic will need to either create a connection, or get an existing connection from the outside. This becomes unmaintainable in the long run. Connection management however is a cross-cutting concern; you don't want the business logic to be concerned in such low level concern.

You should start by splitting the `IRepository` into two different interfaces:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    User GetUser();
}

public interface IConnectionFactory
{
    IDisposable CreateConnection();
}
```

Instead of letting business logic manage the connection itself, you can manage the transaction at a higher level. This could be the request, but this might be too course grained. What you need is to start the transaction somewhere in between the presentation layer code and the business layer code, but without having to having to duplicate yourself. In other words, you want to be able to transparently apply this cross-cutting concern, without having to write it over and over again.

This is one of the many reasons that I started to use application designs as described [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) a few years ago, where business operations are defined using message objects and their corresponding business logic is hidden behind a generic interface. After applying these patterns, you will have a very clear interception point where you can start transactions with their corresponding connections and let the whole business operation run within that same transaction. For instance, you can use the following generic code that can be applied around every piece of business logic in your application:

```
public class TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated;    
    public TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated) {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command) {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
            this.decorated.Handle(command);
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }   
}
```

This code wraps everything around a `TransactionScope`. This allows your repository to simply open and close a connection; this wrapper will ensure that the same connection is used nonetheless. This way you can inject an IConnectionFactory abstraction into your repository and let the repository directly close the connection at the end of its method call, while under the covers .NET will keep the real connection opened.

Answer (score 2):

Create a repository factory that creates `IDisposable` repositories.

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable {
   User GetUser();
   //other methods, doesn't matter
}

public interface IRepositoryFactory {
    IRepository Create();
}
```

You create them within a using and they are disposed of when done.

```
using(var repository = factory.Create()) { 
    var user = repository.GetUser(); 
    //do something with user
}
```

You can inject the factory and create the repositories as needed.

Comment: Please no, [no factories](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100).

Answer (score 2):

So, you already mentioned that

> we dont want to have long lasting connections in application

which is absolutely right!

You need to open connection in each repository method implementation, execute queries or commands against the database, and then close the connection. I don't see why you would expose anything like connection to the domain layer. In other words, remove CreateConnection() methods from repositories. They are not needed. Each method will open/close it inside, when implemented.

There are times when you would want to wrap several repository method calls into something, but that is only related to ***transaction***, not connection. In that case there are 2 answers:

1. Check the correctness of your [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) implementation. You should have repositories only for [Aggregate Roots](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html). Not every entity qualifies as aggregate root. Aggregate root is the guaranteed transaction boundary, so you should not be worried about transactions anyway out of repository - each repository method call will naturally follow the boundary, since it handles only a single aggregate root at a time.
2. If you still need to execute operations against several aggregate roots in one go, then you will have to implement a pattern called [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). This is essentially a business layer transaction implementation. I don't recommend relying on built-in transaction features into storage technologies for this specific case (several aggregates in one go), because they differ from vendor to vendor (while relational DBs can guarantee several aggregate roots in one go, NoSQL DBs only guarantee single aggregate at a time).

From my experience, you should only need to modify single aggregate at a time. Unit of Work is a very rare case pattern. So, just rethink your repositories and aggregate roots, that should do the trick for you.

Just for the completeness of the answer - you do need to have repository interfaces, which you already have. Thus, your approach is already unit-testable.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing apples with oranges and peaches.

There are three concepts at play here:

- The repository contract
- The implementation details
- Repository lifetime management

Your repository conceptually holds users, but it has a CreateConnection() method that indicates details of the implementation (a connection is needed). Not good.

What you need to do is remove the CreateConnection() method from the interface. Now you have a true definition of what a user repository is (by the way, you should call it that, IUserRepository).

On to the implementation details:

You have a user repository that talks to a database, so you should implement a DatabaseUserRepository class. This is where the details of creating a connection and handling it are stored. You may decide to keep an open connection for the lifetime of the object, or you may decide it's best to open and close a connection for every operation.

On to the lifetime of the object:

You have a dependency container. You may have decided you want your repository to be used as a singleton because your DatabaseUserRepository class implements atomic, thread-safe operations, or you may want your repository to be transient so a new instance is created because it implements a unit of work pattern which means that all changes are saved together (e.g. EF.SaveChanges()).

See the difference now?

The interface allows for unit testing. Any component that needs data from the database can use a mock repository that loads garbage from memory (e.g. MemoryUserRepository).

The implementation provides a repository that stores users in a database. You may even decide to have two versions of this class that implement the interface along with different strategies or patterns.

The lifetime of the repository will be setup according to the implementation details in the dependency container.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a Connection Factory...

```
public class ConnectionFactory
{
    public IDbConnection Create()
    { 
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Now make it a dependency to your repositories, and use it inside you repositories as well... You don`t need an IDisposable repository, you need to dispose the connection.
I'm on the cellphone, so it's hard to give you a more detailed example. If you need, i can edit it later with a more detailed example.

Comment: This is a concrete class that deals with implementation details. The solution lies at the level of abstraction of the interface.

Comment: With the connection factory, he will be able to dispose only the connection, not the repository. That's ok the -1, that was not a complete answer. I was going to edit it later, but I forgot.